# convert mixed date type in pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, epoch

I have a dataframe containing dates in a mixed format (containing epochs for example)

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[1562054799651,'2019-07-02','2007-10-01 00:00:00'],columns=['date'])
```

and I would like to convert to datetime, but if I type

```
pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], errors="coerce")
```

I get

```
0   1970-01-01 00:26:02.054799651 <- THIS IS WRONG SINCE IT SHOULD BE 2019-07-02 08:06:39.651
1   2019-07-02 00:00:00.000000000
2   2007-10-01 00:00:00.000000000
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The problem is that the first date is an epoch in 'ms'....

if I type

```
pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], errors="coerce", unit='ms')
```

I get the

```
0   2019-07-02 08:06:39.651
1                       NaT
2                       NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Is there a solution to get the desired output

```
0   2019-07-02
1   2019-07-02
2   2007-10-01
```

Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0):

you can use datetime package

```
import datetime
s = 1236472051807 / 1000.0
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

i think this may help you